# Invalid Binary/Invalid Signature/missing file in CodeResources issue when submit to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing

I'm intending to submit an update version to App Store. I'm experienced about this archiving -> validating -> distributing thing, so I followed the steps carefully. I've tried more than 20 times submission since yesterday and I always get an "Invalid Signature" rejection (Invalid Binary) after few minutes when upload received, all the same each time rejected automatically by the system.

I searched a lot and tried everything I can do, including cleaning build folder, re-generate certificate and profile, re-sign the package etc. Archiving is fine, validating is fine, everything is fine before Apple processing it. Really got mad by it, it says:

[image: Apple's response]

Finally I used the "codesign" command to check my App. I checked my previous version which was submitted successfully and it returns:

[image: Old one works fine]

And my latest wrong *.app shows:

[image: Wrong one]

Then I opened `*.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources` I got some file references that I'm pretty sure I cannot find them in my project:

[image: Wrong file references]

It feels like those wrong file references are exactly the reason (I'm not sure). I choosed "Create folder references for any added folders" option when adding resources and it looks like:

[image: Resources]

1. Where can I remove those wrong "._*.*" file references?
2. Any other suggestion on how to solve the "Invalid Signature" issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it! The ".*" files won't be copied to target package but will be Hashed in `*.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources`, it makes iTunes server consider this package corrupt.

1. defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
2. defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false

Use command 1 to show all hidden files in Finder and 2 to hide them again. Or use

```
find . -name “.*” -print
```

to show all .* files. And use

```
find . -name “.*” -exec rm rf {} \;
```

to delete them.

And then re-archive and submit it. Waiting for review now!